# scalene trapezoid point of diagonals intersection

Tags: geometry

We have a scalene trapezoid. We know AB and CD bases and the diagonal AC. Be P the point of intersection of the two diagonals. Is it possible to find the general expression for AP?
[I would like to know the formula for AP, if it exists, depending on AB, CD, AC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gfVL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

- Which line segments are the diagonals?
- Since you know two points on each diagonal, you can write an equation for each of the diagonals.
- Solve for the point that is contained in both diagonals.

Comment: My request is about the possibility to answer to the uestion without the use of cartesian plane, but only affine geometry. Thanks

Comment: OK, you may want to edit your question.  "General expression" has different levels of "general."

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-link the diagram you have provided : [trapezoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gfVL.png).

No, it is not enough to know $ AB, CD $ and $ AC $ to calculate $ AP $. Try to think of the three segments $ DC, CA $ and $ AB $ as "rods" with "hinges" at points $ C $ and $ A $. You can deform this linkage in anyway you wish, except for preserving the lengths of the rods and the property that $ AB \parallel CD $. It is easy to see the many variations of trapezoids you can form so, each having a different value for $ AP $ but all have the same $ AB, CD $ and $ AC $.

Comment: I think that if you hold constant AB, CD and AC, the segment AP remains the same, in spite of any deformation